# User profile is displying not properly using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

When i have fire ajax on mouseover, user profile is not displaying but second time when i mouserover on it then it is displaying. I have use tooltip for displaying user profile.

Please correct my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".user_profile").bind("mouseover",function(){
      id = $(this).attr('id')
      user_id=id.split('_')[1];
    $.ajax({
        url: "/admin/inbox/user_profile",
        data: {user_id : user_id},
        success: function(data){
            $("#"+id).qtip({
                content:{
                    text: data,
                    title:{
                        text: "User Profile"
                    }
                },
                style: {name:'blue', tip:true}
            });
        }
    });
});
```

});

Comment: What is .qtip() and are you sure you are using it correctly?

Comment: Yes this is tooltip lib and it is correct

Comment: May be your response is not ready when you do it first time. Can you confirm it by adding some alert or log in success block and it appears before you do the first mouseover

Comment: I have added console.log(data) but it displayed proper output and still profile not display on first mouseover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolve this problem by

I have read the solution:

"Because $.ajax is asynchronous, the mouseover event returns before the qtip is created.

When the page loads, you could run $.ajax to pull back data for all the user profiles displayed in the page in advance, store this data in an array, and then create each qtip with data from the already populated array.
"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var i=0,j=0;
$(".user_profile").each(function(){
    id = $(this).attr('id')
    user_id=id.split('_')[1];
    my_user_ids[i++]=user_id;
    my_ids[j++]=id;
});
$.each( my_ids, function(index, value){
  $.ajax({
    url:"/admin/inbox/user_profile",
    data: {user_id : my_user_ids[index]},
    success: function(data){ 
      myArray[value]=data;
      $("#"+my_ids[index]).qtip({
        content:{
          text: myArray[my_ids[index]],
          title:{
            text: "New User's Profile"
          }
        },
        show: 'mouseover',
        hide: 'mouseout',
        style: {name:'blue', tip:true}
      });  
     }
   });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `$.ajax` is asynchronous, the `mouseover` event returns before the qtip is created.

When the page loads, you could run `$.ajax` to pull back data for all the user profiles displayed in the page in advance, store this data in an array, and then create each qtip with data from the already populated array.

Comment: I'm agree that should be better populate all user data in advance, when page is loaded: page will be more reactive when mouse will be hover ever .user_profile element.
But I wasn't sure that mousehover returns before qtip is created, as mccannf have said.. So I have tried it: he say the truth! :-)

If you don't want to load all profile data before, but if you want to use ajax, you can also create the first qtips (for example by define a .ttip class, that show in a qtip "title" value), then change elements titles with .ajax return. But there's a delay between data reading and their updating.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to bind mouseover: it's already done by qtip plugin. Using bind you generate a "conflict" on events at first mouseover event.
You shound resolve, simply, using jQuery .hover instead of bind:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".user_profile").hover(function() {
    {
        id = $(this).attr('id')
        user_id=id.split('_')[1];
        $.ajax({
            url: "/admin/inbox/user_profile",
            data: {user_id : user_id},
            success: function(data) {
                $("#"+id).qtip({
                    content: {
                        text: data,
                        title: {
                            text: "User Profile"
                        }
                    },
                    style: {name:'blue', tip:true}
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```